# I'm using H264 encoding to encode video capture from a webcam. How do I turn of rc lookahead?

Tags: h.264, x264, latency

I want minimize encoding latency per frame. Right now, there is a high increase in encoding latency on the 46th frame. I think lowering the lookahead value might help with this. How do I do this? 
Capture Resolution is 1080p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using x264 directly, it's `--rc-lookahead 20` for 20 frames. If it's via ffmpeg, it's `-x264-params rc_lookahead=10`.

Although I would suggest to use faster [presets](http://dev.beandog.org/x264_preset_reference.html). Default is medum.

Comment: So I'm using OpenCVs videowrite() function. I know that it uses x264 encoding in the back end. Is there a way to set `--rc-lookahead 20` as a parameter through OpenCV?

Comment: From what I can see, this is not possible. OpenCV does not accept private parameters for x264. You can raise an issue at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues

Comment: Would it be possible to change encoder parameters in the OpenCV sourcecode? Or do I have to into the x264 encoder source code?

Comment: Not familiar with the OpenCV source but search for the x264 API calls initializing the encoder parameters and change those.

Comment: OpenCV does not seem to use x264, See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/ffmpeg/readme.txt.